# Why does this animate callback not wait until the animations complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Both animations are being called at the same time (sometimes multiple times)....

```
<div id="home-bt" class="button"></div>
<div id="about-bt" class="button"></div>
<div id="beauty-bt" class="button"></div>
<div id="pamper-bt" class="button"></div>
<div id="gallery-bt" class="button"></div>
<div id="news-bt" class="button"></div>
<div id="contact-bt" class="button"></div>
</div>

</div>
<div class="page-container" id="home">
home

</div>
<div class="page-container" id="about">
about

</div> etc...
```

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".page-container").hide();


 $("#home-bt").click(function() {
$(".page-container").hide(2000, function(){
    $("#home").show("slow");
  });  }); etc.....
```

I've also tried this with same result...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".page-container").hide();


 $("#home-bt").click(function() {
$("#about,#beauty,#pamper,#gallery,#contact,#news").hide(2000, function(){
    $("#home").show("slow");
  });  });
```

Comment: Can you explain better or build a fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

it will work if you implement something like this:

```
  var waiter = setInterval(function () {
                            if (!$('#something').is(":animated")) {
                                clearInterval(waiter);
                                $('#animateafterwait').show("fade", {}, 1000);
                            }
                        }, 300);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have initially hidden the `.page-container` by adding `$(".page-container").hide();`

If you click once at the selector and then click again, then it waits for the time specified to show it.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/RCA9k/2/)